# Laravel Blade: HTML Checkbox is set to true but still not checked

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

This is crazy. When I go to MySQL the checkbox value is stored as true. Xdebug is also showing value as 'true'. When I go to Google Chrome and check the value of the checkbox, it is also showing 'true'. BUT for some crazy reason the checkbox is not checked. What gives?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
  <div class="ml-3"><label style='color:darkred; font-weight:bold;' for="staff">Staff</label></div>
   <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" value="{{$child->staff}}"> </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to set the `checked` attribute for the checkbox based on your database value and not the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `checked` attribute of your `checkbox`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$child->staff}}" @if(conditional) checked @endif>
```

Replaceing `conditional` with whatever logic you have which I assume is your `boolean` value obtained from your database. If this is the `$child->staff` statement, then you would use:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$child->staff}}" @if($child->staff) checked @endif>
```

Comment: could you please be so kind as to have a look at a follow up question I just posted on the same theme - Many thanks! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712090/laravel-blade-checkbox-sends-null-value-to-database