# Laravel Blade : Checkbox sends 'null' value to database

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I don't get it. My Checkbox sends a 'null' value back to my controller when checked. If it is in the DB it will come back checked, but the moment I uncheck it, and then check it again, my form sends a 'null' value What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="col">
  <input type="checkbox" name="staff"   @if($child->staff == 'true') checked @endif >
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide a `value`, currently it doesn't have one.

Comment: So would that be value=“staff” like the name?

Comment: you are storing the word `'true'` in your table?

Answer (score 3):

The `checked` attribute just determines whether or not the checkbox should be included in the `post` request. The `value` attribute determines what the value of the checkbox will be if it is `checked` and therefore included in the form submission.

If you do not specify a `value` and the checkbox is included in the `post` request, its value will be `on`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="staff" id="staff">

"staff" => "on"
```

If you want a `true` value, you'll need to set it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="staff" value="true"
    @if($child->staff == 'true') checked @endif>
```

Even though in the above example the `value` of the checkbox is `true`, if it is not `checked` it will not be included in the submitted form request and so you have a `false` value (technically).

**Update**

> I want to be able to toggle between true and false. When I toggle the checkbox to empty it still passes a null to the DB. Any ideas?

Checkbox values are `strings` so you will need to perform a conversion to the desired value yourself and then store that in the database. An example of this could be achieved is below:

```
public function update(Request $request, Staff $staff)
{
    // Perform some validation on the incoming Request
    $request->validate([
        'staff' => ['in:true,false']
    ]);
    
    // Assuming we get here, data is valid
    
    // If the Request object has a key named 'staff'
    // then the checkbox was checked (true).
    // If there is no key named 'staff'
    // then the checkbox was not checked (false)
    $staff->child = $request->has('staff');
}
```

Comment: You are a rock star. However, I want to be able to toggle between true and false. When I toggle the checkbox to empty it still passes a null to the DB. Any ideas? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Vince if you are getting null value from request then  you can check the request value of checkbox into the controller then pass the value to the Database
  $myVar = isset($request->staff == null) ?  if true yourvalue  : if false your value;

Comment: @Vince I have added an example of how you __*could*__ achieve what it is you've asked.